# how to debug a typescript node application in vscode error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In my vscode app I have a folder called apiEngine/

In this folder is my node app.

Why does it not debug in vscode?

[image]

[image]

.vscode\launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Build Project",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\apiEngine\\src\\index.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "smartStep": true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/apiEngine/dist/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

.vscode\tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "build",
            "path": "apiEngine/",
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "apiEngine/tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `"preLaunchTask": "npm: build"`, VS code expects an npm script `build` inside `package.json` in your workspace root (directory containing your `.vscode` folder). It does not want to execute your build task in `.vscode\tasks.json`.

That is also the reason, why you get the error - `package.json` resides one level deeper inside `apiEngine` folder, so VS Code cannot find the script inside workspace root.

#### Solution

In order to invoke the IDE task instead, you can specify a [`label`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) for your build task and set this label instead of `npm: build` in `preLaunchTask`. The task's `path` argument will provide the proper `package.json` location.

.vscode\tasks.json:

```
tasks: [
  {
    label: "npm-build",
    type: "npm",
    script: "build",
    path: "apiEngine/",
    group: "build",
    problemMatcher: []
  },
  ...
];
```

.vscode\launch.json:

```
...
// before: 
// "preLaunchTask": "npm: build"
// after:
"preLaunchTask": "npm-build", 
...
```